# Couldn't download plugin cordova visual studio 2013

Tags: cordova, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-cordova

Unable to add cordova plugins to my project. Althoudh I used following process
run following command to install cordova globally

```
npm install -g cordova
```

Then create new cordova project using

```
cordova start project_name
```

Go to directory and Install plugin using

```
cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.file
```

Copy Installed plugin folder & paste into plugins folder in Visual Studio solution.
Update config file

```
<vs:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.file" version="1.3.1" />
```

Build the Project.

If have a query please let me know.

Comment: It is strongly recommended running Cordova with VS2015. If you have VS2015 installed, please follow [this document](http://taco.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/migrate-to-vs2015/) to migrate your cordova project to VS2015

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason this doesn't work is because the CPR plugin registry for older versions of Cordova (less than 5.0) has been removed. You need to upgrade to a newer version of Cordova that uses NPM to get plugins.

Please see this for more information:

https://cordova.apache.org/announcements/2015/04/21/plugins-release-and-move-to-npm.html

Also note that the plugin names have changed. org.apache.cordova.file is now cordova-plugin-file.